# error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 while installing python glove

Tags: python-3.x

I am using the command "pip install glove_python". But it is giving me the below error:

`Running setup.py install for glove-python ... error
    Complete output from command /Users/mmt6384/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/xf/hy2wkn4s3nd98k159rpws03nnt3rbk/T/pip-install-eio_81ve/glove-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/xf/hy2wkn4s3nd98k159rpws03nnt3rbk/T/pip-record-9ljtw6cb/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running build_ext
    building 'glove.glove_cython' extension
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/mmt6384/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/mmt6384/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/mmt6384/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -c glove/glove_cython.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/glove/glove_cython.o -fopenmp -ffast-math
    clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "/Users/mmt6384/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/xf/hy2wkn4s3nd98k159rpws03nnt3rbk/T/pip-install-eio_81ve/glove-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/xf/hy2wkn4s3nd98k159rpws03nnt3rbk/T/pip-record-9ljtw6cb/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/xf/hy2wkn4s3nd98k159rpws03nnt3rbk/T/pip-install-eio_81ve/glove-python/`

Comment: Are you on OSX? If so then try installing a recent version of gcc from homebrew

Answer (score 1):

You got this error actually **"command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1"**
Based on your os, you have some steps to fix it. First of all, make sure you already activate your virtual environment. Visit [this site](https://gist.github.com/Geoyi/d9fab4f609e9f75941946be45000632b) for installing and activating **virtualenv**. 
your Python version is **3.6** you need to install **Python Development Package**.

deb based : `sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev`  [link:](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/python3.6-dev)

rpm based : `sudo yum install python36u-devel` [link:](https://pkgs.org/download/python36u-devel)

if you don't have '**gcc**' package you'd better install it before.